# Changing Nemo's Text color using a GTK 3.20+ theme

Tags: theme, gtk3, nemo

I have this issue with a certain theme that I love. I am editing the theme currently and I am having issues locating where the `nemo` bar (with the URI and buttons such as back, forward, up, etc are located) is in the `gtk.css` file. I have already been able to change the titlebar font colors, and now I want to change Nemo's text color. The URI buttons text color is too dark to see and it is invisible compared to the background. Here is an example:

[image: Nemo]

Where the Home icon is, there should be my username next to it, but it is invisble. I want to change it to where the text is light, like in the selected button.

Is this possible?

The theme in question is called [Matcha](https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1187179/).